# Attempting to use PyInstaller with Selenium and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, webdriver, pyinstaller

I'm attempting to create an application that can search for items on a website the user provides.  I want the application to be able to run by non-Python users.  I attempted to use PyInstaller with the following code.  It ran successfully but upon attempting to get the application to run, the error on the bottom returned.  Just looking for any thoughts to at least point me in the correct direction.  Additionally for reference I added the first few lines of my script to show the libraries and webdriver included.  I am using Anaconda and Spyder as well.

```
!pyinstaller ./product_finder.py --onefile --noconsole --add-binary "./driver/chromedriver.exe;./driver"



from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd

user_report = input("\nPlease enter the web address:\n")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(user_report)
```

#Error Message from Console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "product_finder.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "pkgutil.py", line 637, in get_data
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 344, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\_MEI134402\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
```

#Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd

user_report = input("\nPlease enter the web address you wish to open:\n")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(user_report)

while True:
    introduce = input("\nClick enter to end the program..\n")
    if introduce == "":
        break
```

#Code used for PyInstaller on Anaconda/Spyder:

```
!pyinstaller ./test.py --onefile --add-binary "./driver/chromedriver.exe;./driver"
```

Comment: do you have the latest version of pyinstaller installed ? can you run `pip install -U pyinstaller`

Comment: I actually am using Anaconda and Spyder.  Not sure if that makes this more difficult or not.

Comment: what is the output of `pyinstaller --version`

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: I have added an example of the shortened code that provides that error after PyInstaller completes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
!pyinstaller ./test.py --onefile --collect-data selenium --add-binary "./driver/chromedriver.exe;./driver"

found here: [Error while executing my .exe made with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727994/error-while-executing-my-exe-made-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).